# Netty or plain ServerSocketChannel?

Tags: java, sockets, netty, nio

I would like to create a simple server for serving real time data to clients. I would like to open a socket for each client and communicate with them. In this regard, the networking layer is very simple and straight forward.

I understand that using Java Sockets is not encouraged because of it's blocking nature and it's use of threads for each socket. But I was wondering, should I just use ServerSocketChannel which is non-blocking, or should I turn to a complete framework like Netty. For the former option, I was thinking about using the same application server I am currently using (Tomcat), so it has the advantage of not needing another application server like Netty to setup and maintain.

Comment: Netty is not an application server. You need to do more research if you're confused with such a simple thing. Using a ready made framework will be a lot easier to work with than writing the raw code yourself.

Comment: Do you know about Websockets?